# RTF field merged with email template but it not shows the images while sending mail

Tags: email-template, richtextarea

Created rich text field in user object, merged the field in email template.
while sending mail i am not able to view the image in email.
How can i send email with image?

Comment: Do you have any value in RTF?

Answer (score 0):

As of now this is not possible. It is still in [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZvBNAA0)  stage. As per this link "*Rich text field images are not externally available. Images that we insert into templates either have to be publicly available web links or in your Documents folder and marked as an external id.*"